# Python split a string between different delimiters

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to split a string like this

```py
str = "$$Node_Type<block=begin>Blabla$$Node_Type<block=end>"
```

to something like this:

```py
tab = ["$$Node_Type<block=begin>", "Blabla", "$$Node_Type<block=end>"]
```

but I can also have this:

```py
str = "$$Node_Type1<block=begin>Blabla1$$Node_Type2<block=begin>Blabla2$$Node_Type2<block=end>$$Node_Type1<block=end>"
```

to something like this:

```py
tab = ["$$Node_Type1<block=begin>", "Blabla1", "$$Node_Type2<block=begin>", "Blabla2", "$$Node_Type2<block=end>", "$$Node_Type1<block=end>"]
```

The idea at the end is to print it like that

```
$$Node_Type1<block=begin>
   Blabla1
   $$Node_Type2<block=begin>
      Blabla2
   $$Node_Type2<block=end>
$$Node_Type1<block=end>
```

Does someone has an idea ? Thx

Comment: Well, it looks like `$$` is your "lowest common" delimiter. Have you tried `.split('$$')` for starters?

Comment: If i do that I lose the "$$" for each part and I get something like: ['', 'Node_Type<block=begin>Blabla, 'Node_Type<block=end>\n']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of the fact that `re.split` retains the "splitter" in the results if it's a capturing group, and then:

```
import re

example = "Hello$$Node_Type1<block=begin>Blabla1$$Node_Type2<block=begin>Blabla2$$Node_Type2<block=end>$$Node_Type1<block=end>"

level = 0
for bit in re.split(r'(\$\$[^>]+>)', example):
    if bit.startswith('$$') and bit.endswith('block=end>'):
        level -= 1
    if bit:
        print('  ' * level + bit)
    if bit.startswith('$$') and bit.endswith('block=begin>'):
        level += 1
```

This prints out

```
Hello
$$Node_Type1<block=begin>
  Blabla1
  $$Node_Type2<block=begin>
    Blabla2
  $$Node_Type2<block=end>
$$Node_Type1<block=end>
```